# Timed send on udp network failed for java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, udp

I need to send data over ad UDP *connection* on a time basis (once every 20ms).
I tried using a `Handler` / `Runnable` / `postDelayed()` approach ... it was working fine until **Android 9.0**.
Now I need to use a different approach based on `AsyncTask`:

```
class SendCommandTask extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        try {
            do{
                sendCommands();
                wait(UPDATE_DELAY);
            } while(!isCancelled());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

but it fails throwing an `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` .
I know the problem is the `wait()` call but I cannot find a simple way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Please try to wrap wait into synchronized block synchronized(this) 
 { wait(UPDATE_DELAY); }

Comment: now it throws a `java.lang.InterruptedException`

Comment: @weidgyn but you are catching the exception in the method. It's a normal behaviour that indicates the thread is interrupted while waiting on an object so the thread must finish its work

Comment: then this's not a solution... I mean I need to send data every `20ms` and the thread MUST survive... of course I can shift the `try {} catch {} ` block inside the cycle but this  won't clear the things just hide the rubbish under the carpet :-)

Comment: it's not a solution at all.. the task is terminated by the exception and this will end everything.. (even if I trap the exception inside the loop).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue is to simplify `doInBackground` method executing just a single `sendCommands()` call:

```
class SendCommandTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object[] param) {
        try {
            sendCommands();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

AsyncTask objects are instantiated and executed trough a recurring thread structure:

```
    timerTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new SendCommandTask().execute();

            sendCommandsTimerHandler.postDelayed(this, UPDATE_DELAY);
        }
    };
```

in this specific case a simple timer.
Please note that all this has been wrote to avoid rising of exceptions due to use of network bound resources inside `SendCommands()` calls. In my previous code these calls where executed straight inside the very same timer as above. Now I have to wrap everything like this... looks like a non-sense to me.